# NservicesBus 4.6.1 Blocking Activity

Tags: nservicebus, blocking

We are using NServiceBus 4.6.1 and there is a blocking activity that takes about 2 minutes.

I know that with NServiceBus 6, async await is the solution, but we don’t have time to upgrade NServiceBus now, so what is the recommended approach for NServiceBus 4.6.1?

Or is it possible to use async await even in NServiceBus 4.6.1?

Thanks,
Miguel

Comment: Have you identified what is causing the blocking activity? Could you provide a sample with the same version as you're using to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Our blocking activity is Database Access. We do about 50 Oracle DB accesses per each request message processed.